# help creating a complicated stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

So I am not even sure if this is possible but it really would be awesome to learn and to be able to do this.

What I am trying to do is run 3 seperate queries that return a single row of data and create a single table that can then be used in a gridview in asp.net

query 1

```
SELECT     dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT
(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS bookingcount
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
             dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
             dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
@enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
```

query 2

```
SELECT     dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT
    (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS bookingcount
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR <> 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
```

query 3

```
SELECT     SUM(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS total, COUNT(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS Memberships, 
    dbo.HOMES.USERID
FROM         dbo.HOMES INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SUBS ON dbo.HOMES.HOME = dbo.SUBS.HOME AND dbo.HOMES.JOINED 
    = dbo.SUBS.PAIDON
WHERE     (dbo.HOMES.JOINED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.HOMES.USERID = 
    @USER)
GROUP BY dbo.HOMES.USERID
```

all thre queries return a single row with 3 columns
so i figure this could work the only other difficult part is i want to add a new column

```
query1 userid  total1   bookingcount
query2 userid  total2   bookingcount
query3 userid  total3   memberships
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a UNION statement, all you have to do is get the 3 select statements to return the same amount of fields and in the same order

```
SELECT     'QUERY1' AS QUERYNAME, dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS TOTAL2
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
             dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
             dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
@enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID

UNION ALL

SELECT     'QUERY2' AS QUERYNAME, dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS TOTAL2
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR <> 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID

UNION ALL

SELECT         'QUERY3' AS QUERYNAME, dbo.HOMES.USERID, SUM(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS total, COUNT(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL2
FROM         dbo.HOMES INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SUBS ON dbo.HOMES.HOME = dbo.SUBS.HOME AND dbo.HOMES.JOINED 
    = dbo.SUBS.PAIDON
WHERE     (dbo.HOMES.JOINED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.HOMES.USERID = 
    @USER)
GROUP BY dbo.HOMES.USERID
```

Comment: i didnt think it could be that easy haha

Comment: thanks it worked great the only problem im having is if the user has no data for query 3 it just doesn't show that row, how can i plug in 0's if nothing shows up

Answer (score 1):

this looks like a standard UNION - albeit you need your columns in the same order. Here comes the science (this'll be long)

```
SELECT  'query1',   dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT
(dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS bookingcount
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
             dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
             dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
@enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR = 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
UNION
SELECT    'query2', dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID, SUM(dbo.BOOKINGS.APRICE) AS total, COUNT
    (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID) AS bookingcount
FROM         dbo.BOOKINGS INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TOURS ON dbo.BOOKINGS.TOUR = dbo.TOURS.TOUR INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MAJOR ON dbo.TOURS.MAJOR = dbo.MAJOR.MAJOR
WHERE     (dbo.BOOKINGS.BOOKED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.MAJOR.SDESCR <> 'Cruises') AND 
                      (dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID = @USER) AND (dbo.MAJOR.DIVISION = 'A')
GROUP BY dbo.BOOKINGS.USERID
UNION
SELECT  'query3',dbo.HOMES.USERID, SUM(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS total, 
        COUNT(dbo.SUBS.AMOUNT) AS Memberships    
FROM         dbo.HOMES INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SUBS ON dbo.HOMES.HOME = dbo.SUBS.HOME AND dbo.HOMES.JOINED 
    = dbo.SUBS.PAIDON
WHERE     (dbo.HOMES.JOINED BETWEEN CONVERT(int, @startdate) AND CONVERT(int, 
    @enddate)) AND (dbo.HOMES.USERID = 
    @USER)
GROUP BY dbo.HOMES.USERID
```